# Android Device Monitor JVM Terminated Exit Code 2

Tags: java, android-studio

I updated to Android Studio 3.0 and that's when I started having problems with my Android Device Monitor, it always worked on AS 2.3.x but after the update I'm unable to run it, it give me the following error code:
[Screenshot from the Error MSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAFxF.png)

I can't figure out what's the problem...

Answer (score 5):

1) Go to File -> Project Structure. Look at the jre path under the line "Use embedded JDK (recommended)". For example, mine is: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre. Go there to find the jre folder.

2) Open the path with "monitor-x86_64" in your error log. In your case:
K:\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\

3) Copy the jre folder from 1) to 2).

If you don't have a jre folder in 1), you can also download from Oracle:
[Java SE Runtime Environment 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)